# Can you run an Ethereum node with a USB 3.2 SSD?

Tags: storage, nodes

I've not seen much discussion around running an Ethereum node with an USB 3.2 SSD, like this [one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09VLJ7VBM), with ~1050MB/s read/write speeds and 2TB. Would this work as storage for an ethereum node?

What about usb-c to usb-c SSDs?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it should be enough. A fast SSD drive with at least 1 TB of space (storage capacity will grow over time) is required to run a node.

For usb-c to usb-c SSDs, that won't matter, as long as it's fast and meets the 1 TB requirement.

Comment: Thanks Solomon!